# CoreData seems to be losing attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, database, core-data

I have an Entity named Skeins that appears to be losing two of the attributes and I can't work out why:

```
func insertSkein(brand: String, code: String, type: String, description: String, discontinued: Bool) throws {
        let sk = Skeins(context: self.context)
        sk.id = UUID()
        sk.brand = brand
        sk.code = code
        sk.type = type.capitalized
        sk.skeindesc = description.capitalized
        sk.discontinued = discontinued
     
        self.context.insert(sk)
        do{
            try self.context.save()
        }
        catch{
            print("error inserting skein: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

If I look at the state of sk at the insert line I can see:

```
<Skeins: 0x600002ba1e00> (entity: Skeins; id: 0x6000008ab100 <x-coredata:///Skeins/t9792D8DC-F6B0-4644-BD81-4CC63CE05B0F2>; data: {
    brand = TestBrand;
    brandcode = TestBrandTestCode;
    code = TestCode;
    discontinued = 0;
    id = "F1C7929C-C271-477D-B12F-0B3A11C13008";
    projectSkeins =     (
    );
    sharedSkeinProjects =     (
    );
```

As you can see both skeindesc and type are missing (both definitely have values in the parameters) and I can't find any difference in the way the strings are defined in the database file, so I'm stuck! Any suggestions would be brilliant :)

Thanks,
Becky

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Core Data model? It might be that you need to clean the build folder so an old version isn't being used.

Comment: No this has been there for a long while now - I only found it because I'm writing tests and those two attributes fail as they don't have any value/are missing.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem but there is no need to call `insert`; you specified the context when you created the entity, so it is already inserted into the context

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but why are you doing `self.context.insert` when the object already exists in the context?

Comment: For these kinds of bugs I suggest you set up a fresh project in Xcode and debug there. Maybe copy over your .xcdatamodel file and see if you can reproduce the issue. Maybe later add model files until you isolate the problem.

Comment: It looks like those properties haven't been added to your NSManagedObject subclass. Are you using automatically generated code or manual?  Can you check the subclass code?

Comment: @Paulw11 But the code wouldn't compile if they weren't in the subclass, right? Unless they are computed properties of course...

Comment: Thanks for the insert comments - will take it out! The properties are definitely in NSManagedObject which is manual using the 'Create NSObject Subclass' - I've redone this to make sure it wasn't something out of sync but still seeing the same issue.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I was thinking that they could have been added manually as properties without the `@NSManaged` decorator

Comment: And you are sure there are no computed properties with those names? @Paulw11 Ah, that's a possibility I didn't thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the comments on this - spent a few days getting frustrated with it and then randomly chose a different emulator and it worked fine. So best guess is that when I changed pointing the project at iOS 14 -> iOS 15 the emulator got all confused. Lesson learnt - always wipe the emulator if I'm making big project changes!